# Possible to have an abstraction layer for floating point calculations?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, floating-point

I am making an application, where there are a lot of floating point calculations in equations. There are libraries such as [decimal.js](https://mikemcl.github.io/decimal.js/) and [js-big-decimal](https://github.com/royNiladri/js-big-decimal) to give correct floating point results, but it requires to convert each number and operator into an object, which makes the code hard to read and very time consuming.

**Question**

Does there exist an abstraction layer for floating point calculations, so I can just give an equation like such:

```
const result = giveMeCorrectResult(a * b - c / d + e)
```

, without having to wrap each number and operator into an object?

I suppose one would have a similar problem if one wanted to make a calculator in NodeJS, as the user types in the equation.

Comment: It would have to work as part of a language translation layer (like Babel), and it would probably require a type system because sometimes you really do want floating point (which, incidentally, does give correct results; decimal math systems are technically *less* accurate, because they throw away information).

Comment: @Pointy - More information than IEEE-754 throws away? I find that surprising, but haven't been into it in depth. Anywhere I can read up on that?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder well if you're using BigDecimal for things like "money math", there's clearly a loss of precision. If I have 17 cents (sorry; 17p) and we split it, one of us gets 8 and one of us gets 9.  Now, that said, I am not a maths person.

Comment: With infinite precision systems I guess those are better, but I've only ever used infinite precision integer systems like in Erlang.

Comment: I guess it's situation-dependent.

Comment: `decimal.js` and `js-big-decimal` do not give “correct floating point results.” They give different results. `decimal.js` cannot give a “correct” result for 1/3 because ⅓ is not representable in a decimal format.

Comment: @Pointy - You don't need infinite precision to beat IEEE-754's accuracy, just more than 16 significant digits. :-) But yes, you need to be aware of where rounding kicks in, regardless of what you're using.

Comment: The code `a * b - c / d + e` will be evaluated according to the JS rules, which do not support any kind of operator overloading for `*`, `-`, `/`, or `+`.  So this is impossible as asked.  Method chaining might be harder to read, but at least its behavior is tractable and well-known to JS/TS developers. Trying to suborn the runtime engine to do anything else is going to be surprising and likely fragile, so even if you can figure out some crazy way to do this, I'd recommend against it.